# Package gmutils gives an error

Tags: errors, formatting, packages, geometry, input-encodings

For a standard package **gmutils**, this minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gmutils}
\begin{document}
That's all!
\end{document}
```

gives an error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                    #4  \errhelp \@err@     ...
l.2328 }
        % of |\@whilenum|
```

I tried with latex, xetex, pdflate, on two different computers and also in Overleaf. Any clue?

**EDIT**: I've tracked the error to the following command around line 2270 or so of gmbase.sty:

```
\def\gmu@hashesOut#1#2{%
  \ifnum#1<#2%
  \space\space\space\space
  »\@nx\unexpanded{####\number#1}«%
  \expandafter\gmu@hashesOut
  \expandafter{\number\numexpr#1+1\expandafter}%
  \expandafter{\number#2\expandafter}%
  \fi
}% of |\gmu@hashesbraced|.
```

see my answer for the fix.

Comment: well obviously there is a bug in the package so write the maintainer. But why are you trying to use it? It is certainly not a "standard" package.

Comment: Thank you! Why: the journal's style requires it (journal "Topological Methods in Nonlinear Analysis"). Actually I found a line in one of its files where replacing «» by "" makes it almost work (with other errors), though I don't understand why. I will post this as the answer.

Comment: if you get errors you shouldn't use it. After an error the output is more or less random and you could miss text without realizing it. Complain to the journal. They shouldn't require such an unstandard package.

Comment: Even if you could manage to fix the particular error, the `gm` packages redefine `\begin`, so they can't be used with the last releases of LaTeX.

Comment: Right, any error means the package is unusable. Right, it does give an error about group not closing properly at end of document. Still it did generate the expected output -- at least I could submit the paper :) I wonder how this journal operates at all for last ten years :) Thank you very much for your comments!

Comment: @AlexanderGelbukh Can you point to a source for the journal's template?

Comment: @egreg Thank you very much! I've posted my answer, too, for other authors. I don't quite understand why these two characters are so offensive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I downloaded the template from the journal’s site and the example paper. The template provides copies of the `gm...` packages and the class seems to be maintained by the same author of those packages, which explains why it uses them.

The test paper compiles up to TeX Live 2017.

There is no chance at all that it compiles with later versions of LaTeX.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer, this one applies to the template provided by the journal "Topological Methods in Nonlinear Analysis", which is accompanied by their own copies of some of `gm...` files. The template gives the error mentioned in the question.

What helped was to change the line 2677 of the provided gmbase.sty from (in utf-8)

```
  »\@nx\unexpanded{####\number#1}«%
```

to

```
  ``\@nx\unexpanded{####\number#1}''%
```

With this, the template is still broken, giving the errors

```
(\end occurred inside a group at level 1)

### semi simple group (level 1) entered at line 164 (\begingroup)
### bottom level
```

(@egreg can better explain why) and

```
LaTeX Warning: There were multiply-defined labels.
```

but it still produces usable output (with MikTeX 2.9), with which I at least managed to submit the paper.